# How to Replace Datagridview value in Rdlc Report

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am showing data in `Datagridview` in C# as below:

```
ID      Present      Absent     
1         0            1
2         0            1
3         1            0
5         0            1
4         1            0
```

When I am showing rdlc report then I am storing data in dataset.

In the report I want to display  0 as 'Yes and 1 as 'No'

I am trying `datagrid1[1,i].value.tostring().replace("0","Yes")`, but it is showing in the report as 1 and 0 instead of 'Yes' and 'No'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the Replace function of RDLC. Write this code in RDLC:

For Present Column

```
=Replace(Replace(Fields!Present.Value, "1", "Yes"),"0",No)
```

For Absent Column

```
=Replace(Replace(Fields!Absent.Value, "1", "Yes"),"0",No)
```

Comment: OK but in Rdlc report i have 31 fields so i need to replace it on every text box ???????

Comment: Yes u have replace in all 31 fields